# How to Redirect from Non-WWW to WWW with Traefik 2

Tags: docker, traefik

I would like to redirect from non-www to www.

```
  middlewares:
    redirect-to-www:
      redirectRegex:
        regex: "^https?://(www\\.)?(.+)"
        replacement: "https://www.${2}"
        permanent: true
```

What I would like to do:

Type in the browser:

https://dev.domainname.com

obtain:

https://www.dev.domainname.com

Comment: SO is for programming questions